# Mesh deformed after rigging?

Tags: rigging

The mesh has been rigged

Problem comes in weight painting, I think. I tried to weight paint everything how I was supposed to, but mesh is still deforming when posing. It's scaling up and down (for instance, if you move face) and so on...

Is there anything I did wrong?
Can I somehow make it, so mesh does not scale in posing or animating and is there any alternative solution to my weight painting?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saying that the face "scales" when moved is uncorrect. Instead, mesh is deforming in a different way than expected. The reason lies in weighting, as some vertices are assigned only to the "face" bone while others are assigned both to "face" and "head" bones, as shown in the picures.

[image]

[image]

"A" vertex is the "correct one, as it follows exactly the face bone: face bone is child of the head bone, so the "face" vertices are moving without the need to be assigned also to the head bone: this double assignement is leading to the unexpected behaviours: double assignement (or even triple, or more) is OK only in proximity of joints, where you want the mesh to deform and stretch to get better creases and wrinkles.

Comment: Thank you very much, Does it mean, then, that I have to unsign the wights on bones where they are not needed and the stretching while animating will be normalized? :)

Comment: Yes, if a vertex is assigned to two bones and only one of theese bones moves, the vertex will stay in the middle between the two, while it should follow the moved bone